# Adding ajax to text field in node edit form

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have created a content type "Type A" and added three fields to content type. I want to display value in third field equal to (value of first field - value of second field).

I want to implement the same using ajax functionality. I have created a custom module and alter the "node form" and add ajax to field 1 but ajax is not working on change event of textfield.

Code Snippet:

```
function employee_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    $form['field_total_value']['#prefix'] = '<div id="calculate-total-value">';
    $form['field_total_value']['#suffix'] = '</div>';


    $form['field_value_first']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'employee_login_ajax',
        'wrapper' => 'calculate-total-value',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'event' => 'change',    
    );

    $form['field_value_first']['und'][0]['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'employee_login_ajax',
        'wrapper' => 'calculate-total-value',
        'method' => 'replace',  
        'event' => 'change',        
    );

}

function employee_login_ajax(&$form, &$form_state) { //print_r($form); exit;
  print_r($form_state['values']);
}
```

Comment: Hello. What form elements keeps your first and second fields?

Comment: field_value_first and field_value_second are first and second fields.

Comment: Did you meant `$form['field_value_first']`? Well, you can `dpr($form)` with devel to be sure. The rest is in my answer.

Comment: yes, $form['field_value_first'] and $form['field_value_second'] are two fields.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need ajax, you can do this with jQuery or javascript. Something like this might work.

First, create an external js file and set up your change events.

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        jQuery("#field2").change(subtract_fields);
        jQuery("#field1").change(subtract_fields);

        function subtract_fields()
        {
            if (jQuery("#field1").value != "" && jQuery("#field2").value != "")
            {
                return jQuery("#field1").value - jQuery("#field2").value;
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
);
```

Next, load the external js file using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

Clear your cache and voila.

Comment: Good idea, and faster than ajax, but fails if calculations needs something from database. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: I know that I can do this with jquery or javascript. But, ajax should work which is not working.

Comment: If you're just subtracting two values that exist on the form, I don't see why you would need ajax.

Answer (score 2):

In ajax callback you are not supposed to print form part you want updated. You are supposed to return form part that needs updating. And you can set field's value using `$form_state['input']`.

```
function employee_login_ajax(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['input']['field_total_value'] = $your_value;
  return $form['field_total_value'];
}
```

Ah, and don't forget `<input>` usually does not support `change` event. You can use one of the following instead:

- `keyup`
- `blur`
- maybe `input`, this one depends on browser

Or don't set `['#ajax']['event']` at all, to let Drupal decide.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But issue is that when I enter any value in field_value_first and leave it, ajax does not work on the same. I have add print_r in the ajax callback only to check ajax is working or not.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola answer updated

Comment: I added comment before I got your update answer.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola yea, your comment made me update my answer :)

Comment: Before, I did not set ['#ajax']['event'] and it was not working for me. Then I tried to set ['#ajax']['event'] and hope that it work. Trying with other option but not working.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola define "not working" please. AJAX request is never sent? or is sent and returns with status 500? or what exactly happens?

Comment: Ajax request is never sent. I checked firebug consule, but it did not display any ajax path.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola `dpr( $form['field_value_first'])` and see if you are adding ajax to something with `'#type' => 'textfield'`. It will not work if you happen to add it to some wrapper.